# How to populate wpf combobox in xaml

Tags: wpf, combobox

I need to populate wpf combobox with fixed collection of strings (for example months from january to december).

Comment: where do you have the strings? do you store it in enum? or do you do something else?

Comment: I just added this question because it seems not easy to find answer online.

Comment: You should perhaps put more emphasis on the fact that you explicitly want `string` as item type (and neither ComboBoxItem nor an enum), and that the strings should be written in XAML. Then your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In namespace add declaration:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

then add combobox where appropriate:

```
<ComboBox>
  <sys:String>January</sys:String>
  <sys:String>February</sys:String>
  <sys:String>March</sys:String>
                ...
  <sys:String>December</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Clean way to do it, no double and nested comboboxitems in comboboxitems.

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
<ComboBox > 

<ComboBoxItem Content="January"></ComboBoxItem> 

<ComboBoxItem Content="February"></ComboBoxItem> 

<ComboBoxItem Content="March"></ComboBoxItem> 

<ComboBoxItem Content="April"></ComboBoxItem> 

// .... and so on....

</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I tried this approach first; in code Combobox's SelectedItem returns ComboBoxItem object. What I want is to have string instead.

Comment: `ComboBox.SelectedItem` on get returns an object... Maybe I dont understood your question.

Comment: This is a widely used example, but results in ComboBoxItems packed in ComboBoxItems. ItemsControl.Items should rather be data than UI elements, since WPF creates and wraps the ItemContainer around the data item automatically (ItemsContainerGenerator does it).

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the `ItemsSource` of the combo box to the property of the `List<string>.`